# How to copy a file from one directory to another directory in UNIX

Tags: unix

Ex: I have 2 directories

- dir1

  - file1.txt
- dir2

I need to copy file1.txt into dir2.

Note: `dir2` is not a sub-directory of `dir1`. both are unique directories.

Comment: `cp dir1/file1.txt dir2` (I assumed that the current working directory is parent directory of `dir1`)

Answer (score 4):

```
cp dir1/file1.txt dir2
```

or if you are in `dir1`

```
cp file1.txt ../dir2
```

Comment: glad to be of service

Answer (score 0):

`cp dir1/file1.txt dir2/. -v`

-v Verbosiry